# Rails Active Record validates_precense_of not flashing error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model, null

I have a text box in a rails application that I want to validate the pretense of an input before saving to the db. So, I tried placing a validates_precense_of callback in the correct model (as shown below).

```
class Suggestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :details, :metadata, :suggestible, :user
  belongs_to :suggestable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
  serialize :metadata, JSON
  validates_presence_of :details
end
```

Instead of the request failing and flashing an error message, the request is successful, and no suggestion record is ever saved in the suggestions table.

I've debugged and confirmed (see controller below) `@suggestion.details.blank?` and `.empty` return true is the text box is empty.

Here's the controller action:

```
  def select_patients
    @rx_search_request = RxSearchRequest.find(params[:id])
    @groups = []
    params['selected_patient_group'].each do |id, selected|
      @groups << id if selected == "true"
    end

      unless @groups.blank?

        @rx_search_request.select_multiple_patient_group_ids(@groups)

        unless @rx_search_request.approval_status_reason_patients_and_approval? ||
          @rx_search_request.approval_status_reason_requires_approval?
          @rx_search_request.needs_consolidation!
          # @rx_search_request.approve! approved_by: current_user
          @redirect_url = rx_search_request_path(@rx_search_request)
          # @message = "Request has been created."
        else
          @message = "Request has been forwarded to your admin for approval."
        end

      end
    if params.keys.include? "suggestion"
      #we are submitting a suggestion
      group_ids = params[:selected_patient_group].collect{|k,v| k if v == 'true'}.compact
      metadata = {
        group_ids:group_ids,
        patient_ids:ManualConsolidationPatientGroup.find(group_ids).collect{|g| g.manual_consolidation_patients}.flatten.collect{|_p| _p.id}
      }

      @suggestion = @rx_search_request.suggestions.new({
        details:params[:suggestion_box],
        metadata: metadata
      })
      @suggestion.user = current_user
      @suggestion.save
      # @message = "Your suggestion has been submitted."
      # debugger
      # flash[:alert] = 'Your suggestion cannot be blank' if @suggestion.details.empty?
      flash[:alert] = 'Your suggestion has been submitted.'
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

---

Changed the controller to this

```
unless @suggestion.details.blank?
        flash[:alert] = 'Your suggestion has been submitted.'
      else
        flash[:alert] = 'Your suggestion cannot be blank'
      end
      #debugger
      @suggestion.save!
```

also tried this

```
if @suggestion.save!
        flash[:alert] = 'Your suggestion has been submitted.'
      else
        flash[:alert] = 'Your suggestion cannot be blank'
      end
```

**SOLUTION**

Added bang operator `!` to make correct save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need either to check for the result of `save` call, or to make it `save!` instead for the request to fail:

```
if @suggestion.save
  flash[:alert] = 'Your suggestion has been submitted.'
else
  flash[:alert] = 'Your suggestion cannot be blank'
end
```

If you want the validation error to be shown after AJAX request, you need to add something like this to your `<controller_name>.js.erb` file:

```
<% flash.each do |type, message| %>
  $("#your_element_id").html("<%= type.to_s.humanize %>: <%= message.html_safe %>")
<% end %>
```

...where you should change `#your_element_id` to actual HTML ID of element on your page in which you render flash messages.

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work either. Shouldn't validations be performed in the active record anyways?

Comment: Debugged and found @suggestion.save is false for empty inputs, but the controller still doesn't flash the message. Or else it's flashing the message for only a split second before the next page is loaded.

Comment: I've confirmed the message is being flashed, but the next page is still being loaded. In other words the request is still going through, and no record is ever saved to the db because I still have the `validates_precense_of` callback

Comment: So, what's your current question?

Comment: How can I prevent the request from successfully going through if the text box input is empty?

Comment: Change `save` to `save!`.

Comment: check updates to original post. now when I make the request, the spinner just spins indefinitely instead of returning with a validation error.

Comment: Does your flash message work when response is success?

Comment: Also, look through this section of Active Record Basics guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#validations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85305/discussion-between-kendall-weihe-and-eugzol).

Comment: Flash message is shows when the next page is loaded
or in other words when the request is sucessful
I followed the ruby guide exactly. Instead of the request failing and an error being returned the request spins indefinitely.

Comment: Let us stop for a minute. You wanted the request to fail: `How can I prevent the request from successfully going through...`. Not the request fails just as you wanted to. That is the reason why spinner spins indefinitely – because request fails. What is your next question?

Comment: How can I make the validation error appear on the same page?

Comment: You do that with javascript. I updated my answer. If you have further troubles, update your question with relevant parts of your `app/views` files.

Comment: When I click the submit button now it begins spinning and is rendered useless. Is there a way I can make this button press-able again?

Comment: Change `save!` back to `save`.